# Random timestamp generation in R

Tags: r, date, random, timestamp, random-time-generation

I have data with information about calls (about 3 million rows).

```
caller
user_1   
user_2   
user_3   
user_N
```

I need to create one more column with a random timestamp for each `user` call, i.e. I want to get something like this:

| caller | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2019-12-24 21:00:07 |
| user_2 | 2019-12-27 20:03:19 |
| user_3 | 2020-01-11 19:30:54 |
| user_N | 2020-02-15 22:37:12 |

Due to restrictions, the time can only be between `18:00:00` and `23:59:59` and dates must be in the range from `Jan 1, 2019` to `Jan 1, 2021`.

Is it possible to implement this in `R`? Perhaps there are some functions that can be useful here?
I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given data frame with id's:

```
df <- data.frame(caller = 1:3E6)
```

You could run

```
df$timestamp = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00", tz = "GMT") + 
   floor(runif(nrow(df), max = 365))*24*60*60 + 
   runif(nrow(df), min = 18*60*60, max = 24*60*60)
```

which would add a uniform random number of days, and a random number of seconds between 18 and 24 hours' worth.

We can verify that the timestamps occur in the desired range:

```
range(df$timestamp)
range(lubridate::hour(df$timestamp) + lubridate::minute(df$timestamp)/60)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach of generating random timestamps in a range is by generating a sequence of all possible timestamp in the range by using `seq` function, and then randomly select **n** timestamps from them by using `sample` function. For example if you want to generate 3 random timestamps between `Jan 1, 2021` and `Jan 3, 2021`, in the unit of `second`, you can do:

```
set.seed(1)
seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:00:00") ,as.POSIXct("2021-01-03 23:59:59"), by = "s") |> 
sample(3)

#[1] "2021-01-01 06:46:27 +07" "2021-01-03 04:56:32 +07"
#[3] "2021-01-02 10:33:32 +07"
```

Note: *You can specify your own time zone by using `tz` in `as.POSIXct` function.*

By this approach, you can get 3 million random  timestamps by the following steps:

1. Set the start and the end of the daily range to `18:00:00` and `23:59:59`, respectively.

```
starts <- seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 18:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 18:00:00"), 
       by = "days")
ends <- seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 23:59:59"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 23:59:59"), 
       by = "days")
```

2. Calculate the number of samples for each day

```
ndays = length(starts)
n = 3e6/ndays
```

3. Randomly select n samples from all possible timestamps on each day, and
   the store the samples in a list.

```
sampled_timestamps <- vector("list", ndays)
for (k in 1:ndays) {
      sampled_timestamps[[k]] <- seq(starts[k], ends[k], by = "hours") |>
      sample(n)
}
```

5. Convert the `sampled_timestamps` to a vector to be able to use it as a column in a data frame.

```
v_sampled_timestamps <- do.call("c", sampled_timestamps)
```

Now you can use `v_sampled_timestamps` to fill in the values of the `timestamps` column in your data frame.

```
your_df$timestamps <- v_sampled_timestamps
```